# How to Deploy Azure Service Bus to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Can someone let me know how to deploy the Azure Service Bus solution shown in the image to from Visual Studio 2017 to Azure

[image: deploy]

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The above solution is taken from an existing project, however I don't know how to apply it to a new project or Azure

Comment: Try it first. Keep Googling and come back if you've made a solution and got problems with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Service Bus is a reliable information delivery service for applications. This means that you can use the Service Bus from your applications to send and receive messages in different ways (e.g. queues, topics, subscriptions). This means that this ASP.NET Core Application you have copied from an existing project can be deployed just as any other ASP.NET application to either an (Azure) VM with IIS Server running or to the Azure App Service. This can be done with a right-click on the Application and choosing Publish.

Before publishing you have to make sure that you have a Service Bus created on Azure and that you have adjusted the app.settings or app configuration accordingly (Shared Access Signature, ...).

I suggest you make yourself familiar with the Azure Service Bus fundamentals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-fundamentals-hybrid-solutions